# Gapless audio looping [HTML/JS]

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, loops, audio

I am creating a launchpad within a browser, which loops audio files when a button is clicked. In Microsoft Edge the audio looping is gapless and works great, but when tested in Google Chrome, the audio must have a slight delay on the loop. I'll paste my code below and hopefully someone can help me out. (I'm new to JS so some answers may need explaining to me).

**JS:**

```
var audio = [];
var isPlaying = [];

function sound(id){
  if(isPlaying[id]){
    audio[id].pause();
    isPlaying[id] = false;
    audio[id].currentTime = 0;
  }
  else{
    audio[id].play();
    isPlaying[id] = true;
    audio[id].currentTime = 0;
  }
}

function createAudio(src,i){
  audio[i] = new Audio();
  audio[i].src = src;
  audio[i].loop = true;
  isPlaying[i] = false;
}

var mySources = ['audio/drums/1.wav'];
```

**HTML:**

```
<img class="item" src="images/button.png" onclick="sound(1);"/>
```